# Haskell type cast problem

Tags: haskell, casting, types

Example code:

```
fac :: Int → Int
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)

main = do
        putStrLn show fac 10
```

Error:

```
Couldnt match expected type 'String'
       against inferred type 'a -> String'
In the first argument of 'putStrLn', namely 'show'
In the expression: putStrLn show fac 10
```

Answer (score 25):

Let's add parentheses to show how this code is actually parsed:

```
(((putStrLn show) fac) 10)
```

You're giving `show` as the argument to `putStrLn`, which is wrong because `show` is a function and `putStrLn` expects a String. You want it to be like this:

```
putStrLn (show (fac 10))
```

You could either parenthesize it like that, or you can use the `$` operator, which essentially parenthesizes everything to the right of it:

```
putStrLn $ show $ fac 10
```

Comment: ($) and (.) are your loving friends  <3